# Inelastic Collisions;

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, energy-conservation

Let Vc'= common velocity just after collision

A bullet strikes a hanging ball and remains buried in it. At what speed were the ball and bullet moving just after the collision?

When solving this problem how is 1/2 mVc'^2 = mgh ? I don't understand how this can be true because isn't there work done to deform the ball?

Comment: the answer to this badly framed question  (no definition of h)  is here http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/ns540_fall08_notes12/ballistic.html

Comment: The problem that you are working is generally called the "ballistic pendulum", and you're problem is that you are failing to notice that there are *two* parts to the analysis. The collision is inelastic and can not be treated with energy but *can* be treated with momentum. On the other hand the swing is subject to impulse and can not easily be treated in terms of momentum, but *can* be treated using energy.